# 3 column layout: middle col have max width, right col is dynamic

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to create such CSS layout without javascript?

- left column: width is 23%
- middle column: width is 43.5%, max width is 550px
- right column: dynamic (stretches to container width)

The main problem is with middle column's max width. Don't know how to make right column dynamic and stick it to middle column's right edge if its width reached maximum value.

Answer (score 0):

I started experimenting about 30mins after you asked the question, then gave up, but the idea of not having a `float` on the last `div`(thanks to @MrAlien) made my example work: http://jsfiddle.net/6pJJt/3/.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="col1" class="column">Column 1</div>
<div id="col2" class="column">Column 2</div>
<div id="col3" class="column">Column 3</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%
}
.column {
    height: 100%;
    float: left
}
#col1 {
    width: 23%;
    background: red
}
#col2 {
    width: 43.5%;
    max-width: 550px;
    background: orange
}
#col3 {
    width: 100%;
    background: yellow;
    float: none
}
```

Comment: Same story as with Mr. Alien's solution.

Comment: @vencedor - You may be looking for this: http://jsfiddle.net/tHyyh/. It only works on modern browsers though, and you cannot adjust the width of the columns.